# Pros and Cons: LDA vs Neural Networks

Tags: neural-networks, text-mining, natural-language, word-embeddings

LDA is an older approach for word representations, there are newer methods now like CBOW and Skip-gram. But what are the improvements of these models? Do they improve in every way or does LDA still have some advantages over the newer methods?

I have trouble finding a good source that compares the older vs newer methods for word representations.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain how LDA is a word representation? I see it more as a document representation.

Comment: Perhaps these papers might help: [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.648.8023&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [this](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q15-1016). Also have a look on their references.

Comment: @andrei Thank you very much, these papers are of great help, especially the first one. Then I wonder, how did you find this? I struggle with finding papers for certain topics, any searching tips?

Comment: @Stanko, the fact is, that the second paper "kindly" disagrees with the first one. About finding papers - I make a list of authors who write often on the topics I'm interested in, I look-up some of their papers, the referenced papers, and those who cite it. E.g. for _word embeddings_, look-up some papers who cite [A Neural Probabilistic Language Model](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/bengio03a/bengio03a.pdf). Google says there are about 1300 :) I believe you can find more searching tips on [academia.stackexchange.com](http://academia.stackexchange.com).